# gitignore with prefix ! not working

Tags: git

I have the followin .gitignore file.

```
plugins
code/golang/*
!code/golang/src/goclient
```

I expected that everything under `code/golang/*` would be ignored except `!code/golang/src/goclient`.

What am I doing wrong - do you know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do like this:

```
plugins
code/golang/*
!code/golang/src/
code/golang/src/*
!code/golang/src/goclient/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the exact subdirectory.

```
#exclude everything in golang     
code/golang/*      

#except the src subdirectory
!code/golang/src/* 

#exclude everything in source
code/golang/src/*

#except the goclient
!code/golang/src/goclient
```